# How to add a TapGestureRecognizer with c# to created items from JSON?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uitapgesturerecognizer

so Im trying to Deserialize a JSON file and creat some items from it, so far everything is working well. My problem is that i want to add a TapGestureRecognizer to each item created and i don't know how to do so.

---

```
    List<Categories> categorie = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Categories>>(categoriejson);

 Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
    {
  foreach (Categories c in categorie)
    {
       Image image = new Image
      {
       Source = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri(c.imageUrl))
      };

   image.HeightRequest = 105;
   CategorieLayout.Children.Add(image);
```

---

so I just want to add a tap gesture to each created image. I was thinking about checking the x:name given by default to each image, but i failed to do that to ... any ideas are going to be much appreciated.

Comment: What are you looking to do when the images are tapped?

Comment: I will be deserializing another json file

Answer (score 0):

something like this should work - I'm doing this from memory so the syntax may not be perfect

```
Image image = new Image
{
  Source = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri(c.imageUrl))
};

var tap = new TappedGestureRecognizer();
tap.Tapped += TappedHandler;
image.GestureRecognizers.Add(tap);
```

Comment: Okey great ! but where should I place my actions when the picture is tapped ?

Comment: in `TappedHandler`

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to deserialize a JSON file and creat some items from it,I suggest you use a `ScrollView` to wrap the content.It is likely that one page will not be displayed completely and scrolling is required.YOu can do like this:

```
 public TestPage1()
 {
       StackLayout stackLayout = new StackLayout{};

        ScrollView scroll = new ScrollView();
        scroll.Content = stackLayout;

        foreach (Categories c in categorie) {
            var image = new Image
            {
                Source = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri(c.imageUrl))

                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
            };
            var tapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
            tapGestureRecognizer.Tapped += Image_OnTapped;
            image.ClassId = c.imageUrl;//attach data to image's `ClassId`
            image.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer);


            stackLayout.Children.Add(image);
        }

        Content = scroll;
 }
```

Method `Image_OnTapped`

```
 private void Image_OnTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

      // retrieve parameter from sender's ClassId
        var parm = ((Image)sender).ClassId;


    }
```

**Note:**

The sender of the Tapped event will be the control which the gesturerecognizer is attached to. in your case, an Image. You can attach your data to one of the Image's properties in order to access it from your event handler.

```
 image.ClassId = c.imageUrl;//attach data to image's `ClassId`
```

And get value from method `Image_OnTapped` like this:

```
var parm = ((Image)sender).ClassId;
```

Comment: is it possible to know which picture is tapped ? so that i can connect each one with a diffrent action ? in XAML i used to use x:name